# When should we use 'obligatoire' and when should we use 'nécessaire'?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Is it the same as in English?  'Obligatory' is when something is required because an authority has made it a stipulation and 'necessary' is when something is needed for a practical reason.

Answer (score 6):

In French, those two words are in fact kind of similar, and can be interchanged most of the time.

But like in English, ***obligatoire*** is mostly used when there's some kind of authority behind it.

> J'ai été dans l'*obligation* de m’arrêter lorsque les policiers me l'ont ordonné.

Here we couldn't have used *J'étais dans la nécessité*, because it was an order from the policemen.

> Il est *nécessaire* d'avoir un ticket pour assister au concert.

Here you could also use *Il est obligatoire d'avoir un ticket*.

> J'ai dans mon sac ton mon nécessaire de travail / voyage.

***Nécessaire*** can also be use as a noun in this sentence, referring to what you need to do something.

To sum up, *nécessaire* is mostly used to talk about the need, and *obligatoire* for something that you have to do because there's some kind of authority behind it.